# Default "Reference manager" column width in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a little, but annoying inconvenience with Visual Studio 2013. While refactoring, I often modify references in *Reference Manager*. But widths of columns *Name* and *Path* are always shorter than some projects' names, so I have to widen them every time I open this window, because usually I'm adding reference to some long-named project, eg. *LibraryProjectWithLongName*. It's not big problem, but a bit annoying.

Is there any chance anyone know at least how to change default width values for these columns?

At attached image I'm trying to add reference for *MainProject* to *LibraryProjectWithLongName2* (assume full path doesn't fit in *Path*).

[image: https://s31.postimg.org/dxf07thmj/vs2013_refman_example.png]